# ошибка при запуске bat из java

Tags: java

Пытаюсь запустить bat из java. Выдает ошибку.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
        Process proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c c:/1.bat");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
         }
```

Comment: Сейчас мы соберем на сайте экстрасенсов и узнаем какая у вас ошибка :D Шутка :) Добавьте ошибку в вопросе как текст (кнопка `править`) :)

Comment: Хочу пованговать - диск С: - ошибка доступа. Перенесите файл на другой диск.

Comment: Согласен, не написал ошибку.  <terminated>cmd [java application] C:\user\admin\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdc.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: Роместил файл на диск d, ошибка не изменилась.

Answer (score 0):

добавил `start` и работает

```java
Process proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start d:/temp/1.bat");
```